# Signal handler with more parameters

Tags: c++, signals, ros

I'm working with ROS Melodic and Gazebo 9.9.0 on an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I want to send a "stop" message (a Twist message with all zeros) to the robot when user kills a node.

To handle Ctrl.+C event, I use this:

```
/**
 * Override the default ros sigint handler to stop the robot when user press
 * Ctrl.+C.
 */
void sigintHandler(int sig)
{


  // All the default sigint handler does is call shutdown()
  ros::shutdown();
}
```

But this function doesn't allow to pass more parameters (I need to pass `cmd_vel_pub`).

I have declared this publisher on main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "astar_controller");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  // Override the default ros sigint handler.
  // This must be set after the first NodeHandle is created.
  std::signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);

  /**
   * Topic where we are going to publish speed commands.
   */
  ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>(cmdTopic, 1000);

  // More code...
}
```

Maybe I can declare `cmd_vel_pub` as global.

Is there any way to pass more parameters to `sigintHandler` or do I need to declare it as global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limited list of functions that can be called from a signal handler, see [`man signal-safety`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). For this reason, sending a Twist message may be not possible from within the signal handler context.

The [self-pipe trick](https://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) is often used to handle the signal outside the signal handler context:

> Maintain a pipe and select for readability on the pipe input. Inside the signal handler, write a byte (non-blocking, just in case) to the pipe output. Done.

In addition to that, I recommend writing the signal number byte into the pipe, so that you can use the very same signal handler and pipe for any signal (if suitable).

The thread that wishes to handle the signal must wait for the read end of the pipe to become readable, read that byte and handle the signal. Waiting can be done using an event loop (e.g. `select`, `epoll`, etc.) or a blocking `read` call.

Alternatively, you can use [`signalfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) instead of a pipe (see the example there). Or `sigsuspend` to block and wait on the signal.